# Why is the natural ID generation in this SQL Stored Proc creating duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am incrementing the alphanumeric value by 1 for the productid using stored procedure. My procedure incrementing the values up to 10 records, once its reaching to 10th say for PRD0010...no more its incrementing... however, the problem is it is repeating
the same values PRD0010.. for each SP call.

What could be the cause of this?

```
create table tblProduct
(
       id varchar(15)
)

insert into tblProduct(id)values('PRD00')

create procedure spInsertInProduct
AS
Begin

    DECLARE @PId VARCHAR(15)
    DECLARE @NId INT
    DECLARE @COUNTER INT
    SET @PId = 'PRD00'
    SET @COUNTER = 0
    SELECT @NId = cast(substring(MAX(id), 4, len(MAX(id))) as int)
    FROM tblProduct group by left(id, 3) order by left(id, 3)
    --here increse the vlaue to numeric id by 1
    SET @NId = @NId + 1
    --GENERATE ACTUAL APHANUMERIC ID HERE
    SET @PId = @PId + cast(@NId AS VARCHAR)
    INSERT INTO tblProduct(id)values (@PId)

END
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
SELECT @NId = cast(substring(MAX(id), 4, len(MAX(id))) as int)  
    FROM tblProduct group by left(id, 3) order by left(id, 3)
```

To

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        @NId = cast(substring(id, 4, len(id)) as int)
FROM tblProduct  order by LEN(id) DESC, ID DESC
```

You have to remember that

```
PRD009
```

is always greater than

```
PRD0010
```

or

```
PRD001
```

All in all, I think your approach is incorrect.

Your values will be

```
PRD00
PRD001
...
PRD009
PRD0010
PRD0011
...
PRD0099
PRD00100
```

This will make sorting a complete nightmare.

Comment: astander->exactly you are right...its working fine..thanks for ur reply

Comment: An additional problem is that this technique will not produce unique IDs with concurrent inserts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to astander's analysis, you also have a concurrency issue.

The simple fix would be to add this at the beginning of your proc:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

And add a `COMMIT` at the end. Otherwise, two callers of this stored proc will get the same MAX/TOP 1 value from your table, and insert the same value.

Also, you can and should prevent these duplicates from existing by adding a key to your table, for this column. If you already have a PRIMARY KEY on this table, you can add an additional key using a UNIQUE constraint. This will prevent duplicates occurring in the future, no matter what programming errors occur. E.g.

```
ALTER TABLE tblProduct ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Product_ID UNIQUE (ID)
```